# Horizontal scroll two rows at once in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal scrollView, where I have 2 rows that swipes as a unit horizontally. Following is the test code where it works but same data is rendered twice. ie. "post 1" in both rows of 1st column and "post 2 in both rows of 2nd column". What I need is "post 1" and "post 2" in 1st column, "post 3" and "post 4" in 2nd column and so on. Its like table layout with 2 rows and couple of columns in a horizontal scrollview.

https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/multipleloop

```
renderRow(item) {
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: 5 }}>   
        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            marginBottom: 1,
          }}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </View> 

        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            marginBottom: 1,
          }}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
          {this.state.data.map(item => this.renderRow(item))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split your array into multiple arrays of size 2, something like below

```
var arrays = [], size = 2;
while (this.state.data.length > 0)
    arrays.push(this.state.data.splice(0, size));
```

Use `FlatList` with `horizontal={true}` property

```
<FlatList data={arrays}
          horizontal={true}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderRow(item)} />
```

and your `renderRow` will look like this

```
renderRow(item) {
    return (
        <View style={{ margin: 5 }}>
            <View style={{
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                width: 200,
                height: 100,
                marginBottom: 1,
            }}>
                <Text>{item[0].title}</Text>
            </View>
            {item.length > 1 ?
                <View
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'green',
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100,
                        marginBottom: 1,
                    }}>
                    <Text>{item[1].title}</Text>
                </View> : null}
        </View>
    );
}
```